# The mainAxisSize property of the Row inside the ListViewBuilder or ListView does not work

Tags: flutter, listview, row, min

The `mainAxisSize` property of the `Row` inside the `ListView.builder` or `ListView` does not work.

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // not working
        children: [
          Text(index.toString()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

I expected the `MainAxisSize.min` property to shorten the `Row`, but it did not.

Comment: Try this wrap ur Row inside of FittedBox & remove mainAxisSize.min. FittedBox( child: Row() ),

Comment: This did not work

Comment: this is really an easy solution. just wrap ur Container inside UnconstrainedBox(child: Container(),) & remove MainAxisSize.min

Comment: This worked but centered the items in it. For this, I can wrap the UnconstrainedBox with a Row and fix it, but this time I won't need the UnconstrainedBox :). Yes, it was an easy problem. I wrapped the top Container with Row. Based on Alex's answer, I solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` always make the `children` to cover the parent width.
So as you requirement you can remove the `Container` over `Row` and wrap the same `Container` with `Text` as following..

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),child: Text(index.toString())),
      ],
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Based on your answer, I wrapped the Top Container with Row and it worked.